# Unity / How do I change the color of the "Screen" based on the Object's depth's (as a Screen Effect)?

Tags: unity, shaders, directx11

Yesterday I asked and solved my problem:

[Unity / How do I change the color of an object based on its depth?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124917/unity-how-do-i-change-the-color-of-an-object-based-on-its-depth)

Today I tried to change the script(from yesterday) and apply it to the camera and it did not work.

Every pixel which is printed on the Display has a depth (float), is that right?

Based on that Depth - I want every object to fade grey, relative to the screen distance to that "pixel".

Is this possible?

Or do I have to use that vertex/fragment shader on every single Object and Plane and Sky and everything in the world?

Comment: You jibbah-jabbah a lot.  Try to keep your questions concise.

Comment: Please avoid creating multiple accounts. Visit [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have them merged.